# $.get request shopify error

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I've have weird issue, on dev theme (preview mode)  $.get request works fine -> https://woolet-co.myshopify.com/blogs/news

but on active theme on main domain https://woolet.co/blogs/news there is an error, I can't figure it out why its happening.

If you try this code in console on both URLs you will see the response code error on main domain:

```
$.get('/admin/blogs/19692355/articles/229491718.json', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
});
```

I guess that it's connected with domains, on https://woolet-co.myshopify.com/blogs/news $.get request works fine and on https://woolet.co/blogs/news it shows error in console.

I've tried to execute $.get request through Shopify Private App with login and password included but without any result.

Comment: Your path to JSON (https://woolet-co.myshopify.com/admin/blogs/19692355/articles/229491718.json) is returning a 404 error

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why on https://woolet.co its not working and on https://woolet-co.myshopify.com it works fine

Answer (score 1):

This isn't working for you because your XMLHttpRequest is for a different domain than the one the page is on.

For this to properly work, you need to enable CORS. I would also suggest putting in the absolute URL of where this JSON file is located.

Answer (score 1):

It would work on your preview mode. Because there both shop url and admin url are on same domain

https://woolet-co.myshopify.com/blogs/news

But when you try to browse using your real domain "https://woolet.co/". The domain from where you are making the get request and the domain from where the file is coming becomes different. ( https://woolet-co.myshopify.com/admin/blogs/19692355/articles/229491718.json )

As far i know you can not enable cors on shopify

and

It wont work because "https://woolet-co.myshopify.com/admin/blogs/19692355/articles/229491718.json" requires you to be logged it to the store as admin.

Try some other way.

[image]